# Creating queues of tasks at points of time

Tags: cron, at

Does UNIX offer any way of creating queues that start regularly at a particular time, at then lets you gradually add a number of tasks to that queue that will be run sequentially at that time?

I know about `cron` and `at`, however:

- `cron` does not have a queue system.
- `at` doesn't seem to support sequential tasks, and lists tasks in a very unfriendly way ("list all" just prints task number and date, while info about a single a task prints the entire `env`.)

I envision something like this:

```
$ create queue a at midnight
$ add "ffmpeg -i a.mkv a.mp4" to a
$ add "ffmpeg -i b.mkv b.mp4" to a
$ add "ffmpeg -i c.mkv c.mp4" to a

$ create queue b at noon
$ add "mysqldump ..." to b

$ list queue a
RUNNING  ffmpeg -i b.mkv b.mp4
NEXT     ffmpeg -i c.mkv c.mp4

$ mail
>N 1 Task Daemon Thu Sep 1 00:23 <user@localhost> ffmpeg -i a.mkv a.mp4
```

For the record, my actual need is to schedule CPU/time demanding tasks at night while my laptop is in a room with a closed door so I can't hear the fan (or feel the boiling heat from the CPU).

Answer (score 2):

You may decry `at`, but it does part of what you want if you use its *batch* features.  If you give the `at` command the single uppercase letter name of a queue, eg `-q M`, then any commands on that queue will only be run at the requested time *if* the system load is less than 0.8, and it will space out starting the jobs by 60 seconds.

You can alter the load and interval with options `-l` and `-b` to the `atd` daemon. The jobs are run in order of submission, and `atq -q M` lists just the jobs on the given queue.

Answer (score 1):

Cron and at are the only things that are commonly installed on Unix systems. But there are fancier [job scheduling systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler#Batch_queuing_for_HPC_clusters) out there. There is a standard interface to queue a job: [`qsub`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/qsub.html). If you want to schedule a job for the next midnight:

```
{ echo '#!/bin/sh'; echo 'ffmpeg -i a.mkv a.mp4'; } >a.script
qsub -a $(date -d 'tomorrow 0:00' +%Y%m%d%H%M) a.script
```

Ubuntu includes two job schedulers that implement the POSIX (NQS-derived) interface: [TORQUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TORQUE) and [Slurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager). There are other open-source implementations and I have no particular advice on choosing one.

Answer (score 0):

If these are single run jobs (as opposed to periodic ones), then the easiest method I think is to just use `tmux` and `sleep`. Open a tmux session, and do this:

```
$ echo "ffmpeg -i a.mkv a.mp4" > midnight.sh
$ echo "ffmpeg -i b.mkv b.mp4" >> midnight.sh
$ let secs_till_midnight=$(date -d "`date -d '+1 day' +%F`" +%s)-$(date +%s)
$ sleep $secs_till_midnight && sh midnight.sh
```

Schedule more jobs in new panes/windows from the same session, and when you're done, detach from that session. That's it! Your very own, homemade scheduler!

Even though you can't list running tasks, add these 2 lines at the beginning of the `midnight.sh` for extra visibility:

```
set -x
exec 2>midnight_err >midnight_out
```

Now, each command will be output to terminal before it is executed, and all output from the command gets redirected to `midnight_*` files.

Now simply attach to that session or `tail` the log files to check the status!